# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel: Change background outside carousel-element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I use the standard carousel from the twitter bootstrap framework: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Now I want to change the background with each slide.
The problem is, that the background is not in the "carousel-inner" DIV.

Is there any solution to trigger the background outside this div? Or even better, outside carousel?

Comment: sorry I don't get it.. We are using carousel for images right? Then I tried replacing the image to text and added background-color in `<div class="item">` and it works

Comment: Ah no, we use the carousel only for text.
This text is displayed in a little box with fixed position.

The background-image is behind this box. when it slides, the fixed box  with the text-slides should stay in it's place

Comment: then add a style example `<div class="item active" style="background-color:red;">` then so on..

Comment: see above, comment wasn't finish, sorry.
the background-image is not in the item-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to break down the logic, it sounds like what you want to do is:

1. Intercept the slide event for the carousel
2. work out the slide being shown
3. '*do something*' depending on the slide (e.g. change a background image in another element).

Have a look at the below jsfiddle:

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U979G/1/)**

Crucially, the jQuery:

```
// This triggers after each slide change
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
  var currentIndex = carouselData.getActiveIndex();
  var total = carouselData.$items.length; 
  var slide = (currentIndex + 1);
  // do something depending on the slide number..
});
```

What you probably want to do is replace the line:

`// do something depending on the slide number..`

with code to change your background images outside the carousel, for example:

```
$('#background_image_element').css('background-image', 'url(myPicture_'+slide +'.jpg)');
```

Comment: var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'));

since Bootstrap 3.2